# Creating a Hash with values as arrays and default value as empty array

Tags: ruby

I want to create a Hash in Ruby with default values as an empty array

So, I coded

```
x = Hash.new([])
```

However, when I try to push a value into it

```
x[0].push(99)
```

All the keys get `99` pushed into that array. How do I resolve this?

Comment: `Hash.new { [] }` is what you want.

Comment: @CarySwoveland this will return a new array without storing it in the hash

Comment: you could use `x = Hash.new { [] }` if you were adding values via `|=` (e.g. `x[0] |= [99]`) since that will create a new array and assign it to `x[0]`. I think it's probably better to be explicit about it like in the answers below.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Lakshmi is right. When you created the Hash using `Hash.new([])`, you created **one** array object.

Hence, the **same** array is returned for **every** missing key in the Hash.

That is why, if the shared array is edited, the change is reflected across all the missing keys.

Using:

```
Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
```

Creates and assigns a **new** array for each missing key in the Hash, so that it is a unique object.

Comment: What is the difference between `Hash.new(Array.new)` and `Hash.new{Array.new}`?

Comment: @vildhjarta `Hash.new(Array.new)` creates the array only once, before passing the new array to the Hash constructor, so all missing objects share that same array. `Hash.new {Array.new}` creates a new array every time the block is called (`{Array.new}`), which produces a new array for every missing object.

Answer (score 34):

```
h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = [] }

h[0].push(99)
```

This will result in `{0=>[99]}`

---

When `Hash.new([])` is used, a single object is used as the default value (i.e. value to be returned when a hash key `h[0]` does not return anything), in this case one array.

So when we say `h[0].push(99)`, it pushes `99` into that array but does not assign `h[0]` anything. So if you output `h` you will still see an empty hash `{}`, while the default object will be `[99]`.

---

Whereas, when a block is provided i.e. `Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = [] }` a new object is created and is assigned to `h[k]` every time a default value is required.

`h[0].push(99)` will assign `h[0] = []` and push value into this new array.

Comment: This is confused.  Hash.new([]) creates one object and assigns it to all new entries.  Hash.new{[]} creates an object per entry and throws it right away; it is equivalent to Hash.new(nil).