# Check hash if key exists; if not, create array and append value

Tags: ruby

Example as follows:

```
if house['windows'][floor_1]
  house['windows'][floor_1] << north_side
else
  house['windows'][floor_1] = [north_side]
end
```

Best way to check for existing key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Hash with values as arrays and default value as empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367487/creating-a-hash-with-values-as-arrays-and-default-value-as-empty-array)

Comment: One common way of doing this (which some claim is faster than using a default proc): `h = {}; h[:a] = (h[:a] || []) << 1 #=> [1]; h[:a] = (h[:a] || []) << 2 #=> [1, 2]`.

Comment: What is `house`?

Answer (score 4):

The fact that `house['windows']` is an element in a hash already is a bit of a red herring, so I will use `windows` as a variable referencing a hash.

Set up a default value for the `windows` hash, so that any non-preexisting key is assigned an array value:

```
windows = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```

Now you can append (`<<`) to new hash elements automatically.

```
windows['floor_1'] << 'north_side'

windows # => {"floor_1"=>["north_side"]}
```

For your specific case, replace `windows` with `house['windows']`.

---

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, this behavior can be added to an already-instantiated hash:

```
windows.default_proc = proc {|hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```

Comment: What to do if `windows` is external data and we can't create it?

Comment: @mechnicov Then you can set the default proc with [`#default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D). `windows.default_proc = proc { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }`

Comment: @JohanWentholt, good idea. I asked this question so that user513951 improves the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

```
house['windows'][floor_1] ||= []
house['windows'][floor_1] << north_side
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your Hash, I imagine:

```
house = { windows: { floor_0: ['f0'] } }
```

You can check the existence of a key using [`Hash#has_key?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F)

```
house[:windows].has_key? :floor_1 #=> false
```

So you can create it:

```
house[:windows].merge!({floor_1: []}) unless house[:windows].has_key? :floor_1
```

---

Better if you define a defalt value using for example [`Hash#default_proc=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D):

```
house[:windows].default_proc = proc { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
```

So you can

```
house[:windows][:floor_3] << 'f3'

house #=> {:windows=>{:floor_0=>["f0"], :floor_1=>[], :floor_3=>["f3"]}}
```