# Group by specific array value in hash and include key

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I am trying to find out if it is possible to sort a Hash by a specific value if there are multiple values saved to a key.

Example Code:

```
{
key1: ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"], 
key2: ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"],
key3: ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]
}
```

I would like to be able to sort by the values in `Value2` or by `Value1` or any specific value.

If `key1` and `key2` have the same `Value2` they will be returned as:

`{Value2: [key1, key2]}`

Example:

`Value2` representes pets:

- For all the `Value2` that have dog, the key will be saved under a new key, dog.
- For all the `Value2` that have cat, it will gather all keys that have `Value2` as cat and group it.

```
{cat: ["key1", "key2"], dog: ["key3"]}
```

I am working in Ruby and VScode. I do not want to use an array or nested array because this is not efficient.

---

Given

```
{
key1: ["Cop", "dog", "house"],
key2: ["doctor", "cat", "apartment"],
key3: ["Chef", "dog", "house"],
key4: ["Cop", "cat", "apartment"]
}
```

Expected Output if asked to sort by the values in `value2`

```
{
dog: [key1, key3],
cat: [key2, key4]
}
```

Comment: For example, "I have `[1,2,3]` and I want `[3,2,1]`." Like that.

Comment: If it helps, pretend you're writing a test case for what you want.

Comment: @Schwern If i have a bunch of keys set up like ```{key: [Value1, Value2, Value3]}```. I want to be able to look at all the Value2's. For all the keys that have ```dog``` as ```Value2```, group the keys together. For all the keys where ```value2``` is ```cat``` I want them grouped together.

Comment: Can you write that more like: "I have `{ key1: ["dog", "cat", "badger"], key2: ["parrot", "cat"], key3: ["dog", "parrot"] }` and I want `{ ...something... }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248868/discussion-between-spotomic-and-schwern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `#each_with_object` to build up a hash as we iterate over the keys in the original hash.

```
data = {
    key1: ["Cop", "dog", "house"],
    key2: ["doctor", "cat", "apartment"],
    key3: ["Chef", "dog", "house"],
    key4: ["Cop", "cat", "apartment"]
}

data.keys.each_with_object(Hash.new([])) { |k, h| 
  h[data[k][1]] += [k] 
}
# => {"dog"=>[:key1, :key3], "cat"=>[:key2, :key4]}
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be about sorting, but rather grouping.

It's a matter of iterating through each pair and building a new hash of the matching keys and values.

```
# A Hash where the default value is a new empty array.
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367487/creating-a-hash-with-values-as-arrays-and-default-value-as-empty-array
grouped = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }

# Iterate through the Hash
h.each { |key, things|
  # Get the 2nd thing
  thing = things[1]

  # Add its key to the thing's group
  grouped[thing] << key
}

p grouped
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the optimal solution but it returns the expected result. The code is at least groups by value and includes the key, resulting in:

`{"cat"=>[:key2, :key4], "dog"=>[:key1, :key3]}`

```
hash = {
    key1: ["Cop", "dog", "house"],
    key2: ["doctor", "cat", "apartment"],
    key3: ["Chef", "dog", "house"],
    key4: ["Cop", "cat", "apartment"]
}

def group_by(animal, hash)
  keys = hash.select{|key, value| value[1] == animal }.keys
  {animal => keys}
end 

a = group_by("cat", hash)
b = group_by("dog", hash)
a.merge(b)
```

I am sure there is a more "direct" solution.